# Instructs Heroku "apache fpm_custom.conf php memory limit configs" to use values from an environment variable

Tags: php, heroku

I have fpm_custom.conf which contains the following line.

php_value[memory_limit] = 128M

How can I use a value from an environment variable with a default value if none were found